# Zoo Visitor registration and autologin issues

Tags: registration, zoo

I am trying to allow the user to autologin on registration rather than activate via email, and have set 'Require Member Account Activation?' to 'No activation required' and turned 'Require email confirmation' to 'No' in Zoo Visitor settings.

With these both set, when I go to register on the front end, it still sets my new account to 'Pending' and doesn't autologin - which I need it to do.

I have tried the standard expressionengine registration form and that worked, creating a new member with the correct member group, rather than 'Pending', so I believe it to be a problem with Zoo Visitor somewhere, but can't figure it out.

I have looked in the database to see if any of the settings are different to what are set in the CMS but everything looks okay.

I have tried adding the 'allowed_groups' parameter and also the autologin but none of these help.

I have also tried adding a field with the member group_id within the registration form but that had no effort either.

The zoo visitor login form still works too so I'm a bit stumped really!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!